# Using Trait, wanted to use CONST but that is not allowed so I tried static

Tags: php

Trying to run this code:

```
trait Publishable {

    static $PUBLISH = 'publish';
    static $DRAFT = 'draft';
    static $SCHEDULE = 'schedule';

    static $STATUS = [
        $DRAFT => 0,
        $PUBLISH => 1,
        $SCHEDULE => 2
    ];
```

I get

'Constant expression contains invalid operations'

What can i do about this?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous but I guess you have problems declaring `STATUS` as a `const`. This is because until PHP 5.6 only scalar values could be used as values of `const`. Since PHP 5.6 your code should work.

Comment: That has nothing to do with it being a trait. You would get the same error if you wrote that in a Class directly. You can't set properties using variables or functions when defining them.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson ok thanks I did not know that

Comment: @maxit It's a [documented feature](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php#example-180) (or the lack of it, to be more precise).